# How can I share a spawned SSH process between multiple procedures in TCL Expect?

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect, procedure, procedures

Edit: I've figured it out by referencing the Exploring Expect book. Please don't hesitate to add to my answer or make other suggestions, though! I will mark this as answered when I am allowed to (2 days from now).

I've looked around and unfortunately I'm not able to find too much on using SSH with expect here on this site.  I am relatively new to Expect but I have been teaching myself with the Exploring Expect book.

My question is: How can I use a single spawned SSH process for multiple tcl procedures?  My workaround right now is to close the SSH connection at the end of procedure 1 and re-spawn a new SSH connection in procedure 2.

Example: (The example is simplified quite a bit and only includes the necessary components to demonstrate my question... My whole program is over 200 lines as of now)

```
;# Proc definition for procedure1
    proc procedure1 {user host pw} {
     spawn /usr/bin/ssh $user@$host
     expect "Password:"
     send "$pw\r"
     expect "#" ;# This is my device's prompt
     ;# From here it does a bunch of stuff... sends commands to the SSH
     ;# session, captures output, builds arrays and lists, etc
     send "exit" ;# Disconnects the SSH session
     return $mylist ;# returns a list of numbers to be used in procedure 2
     }

;# Proc definition for procedure2
    proc procedure2 {resultofproc1 user host pw} {    
     spawn /usr/bin/ssh $user@$host
     expect "Password:"
     send "$pw\r"
     expect "#" ;# This is my device's prompt
     ;# Proc 2 now continues on in the same device using the results (a 
     ;# list) from proc1. 
     return
    }



    ;# Procedure call for first procedure:
    set resultofproc1 "[procedure1 $user $host $pw]"

    ;# Procedure call for second procedure:
    procedure2 $resultofproc1 $user $host $pw
```

Instead of closing the SSH connection at the end of procedure1 and reopening the SSH connection at the beginning of procedure2, how can I send commands from procedure2 to the SSH connection opened in procedure1?  Obviously I would have to remove the sending of exit to keep the connection open.  Assuming this is possible... Is this even a good practice or am I better off separating connections between procedures? If so, can you modify my code example to demonstrate how?

From what I have gathered, I think it has to do with the spawn_id variable.. but I can't figure out how to implement that in my code.  I am currently reviewing chapter 10 "Handling Multiple Processes" in the Exploring Expect book. I will report back if I can figure it out on my own.

Thanks for your assistance!

I have viewed these answers on stackoverflow:

[Tcl Expect Keep SSH Spawn open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599806/tcl-expect-keep-ssh-spawn-open)

[Expect Procedure for SSH Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168744/expect-procedure-for-ssh-login)

[Using procedure for spawing SSH doesn't work properly with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679533/using-procedure-for-spawing-ssh-doesnt-work-properly-with-expect)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm) to declare `spawn_id` as a global var. According to expect's manual:

> CAVEATS
>
> > ...
> >     *Expect*  takes  a rather liberal view of scoping.  In particular, variables read by commands specific to the *Expect* program will  be  sought **first  from  the  local  scope**, and if not found, in the global scope. For example, this obviates the need to place `global timeout` in every procedure  you  write  that uses `expect`.  On the other hand, **variables written are always in the local scope (unless a `global`  command  has been  issued)**.   The  most common problem this causes is when `spawn` is executed in a procedure.  Outside the procedure,  `spawn_id`  no  longer exists,  so the spawned process is no longer accessible simply because of scoping.  Add a `global spawn_id` to such a procedure.
> >     ...

---

You can also take advantage Tcl's [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm) command. For example:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.exp
proc expect_prompt {} {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}
}

proc open_conn {} {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    spawn bash --noprofile --norc
    expect_prompt
}

proc close_conn {} {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}

proc send_cmd { cmd } {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    send "$cmd\r"
    expect_prompt
}

proc main {} {
    open_conn

    send_cmd "echo spawn_id=$spawn_id"
    send_cmd "ps Tu"

    close_conn
}

main
[STEP 102] $
```

Output:

```
[STEP 103] $ expect foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.4$ echo spawn_id=exp6
spawn_id=exp6
bash-4.4$ ps Tu
USER     PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
root   71513   0.0  0.0  2433012    788 s013  R+   12:58PM   0:00.00 ps Tu
pynexj 71510   0.0  0.0  2445360   1572 s013  Ss   12:58PM   0:00.01 bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.4$ exit
exit
[STEP 104] $
```

Comment: Thanks whjm! I will look more into the upvar vs global variable idea.

Comment: The extract from the manual implies that you *only* need to use `global spawn_id` in the `open_conn` proc -- you can remove the `upvar` commands from all the other helper procs. They will get the spawn_id from the global scope automatically. The exception is in the `main` proc, where you explicitly reference the var: there, you can use `$::spawn_id` to get it from the global scope.

Comment: @glennjackman -- I agree `global` is enough and easier for most cases. `upvar` is better when dealing with multiple `spawn`s or writing library code.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was so close!  Had I taken a few more minutes in the Exploring Expect book, I would have figured it out.  Anyways, here is my solution. Hopefully it helps someone else with the same problem.

It has everything to do with the spawn_id variable.  Basically, by default, the send and expect commands interact only with the last spawned process.  Each spawned process is assigned a unique spawn_id value.  You can set the spawn_id of a procedure to the spawn_id of another spawned process.

Here is the code in my original question modified to support the spawn_id variable:

```
;# Proc definition for procedure1
    proc procedure1 {user host pw} {
     spawn /usr/bin/ssh $user@$host
     global procedure1_spawnid         ;# Creates a global variable called
                                       ;# procedure1_spawnid
     set procedure1_spawnid $spawn_id  ;# Assigns the spawn_id of the SSH process to the 
                                       ;# global variable.
     expect "Password:"
     send "$pw\r"
     expect "#" ;# This is my device's prompt
     ;# From here it does a bunch of stuff... sends commands to the SSH
     ;# session, captures output, builds arrays and lists, etc
     return $mylist ;# returns a list of numbers to be used in procedure 2
     }

;# Proc definition for procedure2
    proc procedure2 {resultofproc1} {    
     global procedure1_spawnid
     set spawn_id $procedure1_spawnid   ;# Sets the spawn_id to that of the SSH connection
                                        ;# in procedure1.
     send "show ip interface brief"
     expect "#"
     ;# The show ip interface brief command is sent to the device through the 
     ;# SSH connection opened in procedure1.
     return
    }



    ;# Procedure call for first procedure:
    set resultofproc1 "[procedure1 $user $host $pw]"

    ;# Procedure call for second procedure:
    procedure2 $resultofproc1
```

More information can be found in Exploring Expect, page 233.

If anyone has any suggestions or improvements, please feel free to lay them on me! I am still learning tcl/expect.